# YII2 dependent fields

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have DropDownList:

- Calendar
- Last day
- Text input

And I need:

- if a user chooses "Calendar", the calendar widget appears
- if "Text input", a text input appears
- if "Last day" is chosen, nothing appears

I found many options on the web, but they use AJAX, and unfortunately, I can't make it to work in my case.

I think it can be solved with JavaScript.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php 
    $js = 'function Go(){ alert("ok!");}';   
    $this->registerJs($js, yii\web\View::POS_READY);   
?>

<?php echo $form->field($model, 'condition')->dropDownList($conditionList,
[
    'id' => 'condition',
    'class' => 'dependent-input',
    'onchange' => 'Go()',
]
);
?>
```

Comment: You’ve expressed a need, but what, specifically, is your question? Have you tried writing the JavaScript? jQuery sounds like a good option. For help editing your question, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: Yes, I've tried use jQwery, but I could not get to work it

Comment: If you post your jQuery code, it will help others collaborate with you in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to accomplish the showing and hiding of your calendar and text input widgets.

Your compiled HTML might look something like this:

```
<select class="hide-and-show" name="show-and-hide">
  <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
  <option value="calendar">Calendar</option>
  <option value="text-input">Text Input</option>
  <option value="last-day">Last Day</option>
</select>

<div class="calendar hideable">CALENDAR GOES HERE</div>
<div class="text-input hideable">TEXT INPUT GOES HERE</div>
```

Hiding the `.hideable` elements until they are selected is accomplished with simple CSS:

```
.hideable {
  display: none;
}
```

And a little JavaScript + jQuery can handle the toggling of the hiding and showing of the widgets, like this:

```
var closerClass = "last-day";

$(".hide-and-show").change(function() {
  var selectValue = $(this).val();

  if (selectValue === closerClass) {
    $(".hideable").hide();
  } else {
    var classname = "." + selectValue;
    $(classname).show();
  }
});
```

I've created a [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/YpNLXN) to demonstrate.